# Error 401 when trying to get free/busy slots from shared Outlook calendars using Microsoft Graph Java SDK

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I created two fresh Outlook accounts and shared one's Outlook calendar with the other. Then I tried getting the shared calendar free/busy slots by using Graph API Java SDK:

```java
 final String accessToken = resolveAccessToken(refreshToken);
    final IGraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = client.getClient(accessToken);

    ICalendarGetScheduleCollectionPage iCalendarGetScheduleCollectionPage = null;

    final DateTimeTimeZone startTime = new DateTimeTimeZone();
    startTime.dateTime = RFC339Utils.fromInstant(timeFrame.getStartAt());

    final DateTimeTimeZone endTime = new DateTimeTimeZone();
    endTime.dateTime = RFC339Utils.fromInstant(timeFrame.getEndAt());

    ICalendarGetScheduleCollectionPage iCalendarGetScheduleCollectionNextPage =
        graphServiceClient
            .me()
            .calendar()
            .getSchedule(emails, endTime, startTime, availabilityViewInterval)
            .buildRequest()
            .post();
```

For this request I received an empty response body with a nested inner exception:

```
System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.\r\n   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)\r\n   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.Proxy.Service.EndGetUserAvailability(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.FreeBusyApplication.EndProxyWebRequest(ProxyWebRequest proxyWebRequest, QueryList queryList, IService service, IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.ProxyWebRequest.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.AsyncWebRequest.EndInvokeWithErrorHandling()"
```

Then I tried performing the following request

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/getSchedule
```

with request body

```
{
  "schedules": [
    "joseph.baker.doodle@outlook.com"
  ],
  "startTime": {
    "dateTime": "2019-10-24T09:00:00",
    "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "endTime": {
    "dateTime": "2019-10-30T18:00:00",
    "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "availabilityViewInterval": 60
}
```

cURL command

```
curl 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/getSchedule' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Origin: https://developer.microsoft.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36' -H 'SdkVersion: GraphExplorer/3.0' -H 'Authorization: Bearer {insert access token here}' -H 'Content-type: application/json' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' -H 'Referer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,sr;q=0.7,hr;q=0.6' --data-binary $'{\n  "schedules": [\n    "joseph.baker.doodle@outlook.com"\n  ],\n  "startTime": {\n    "dateTime": "2019-10-24T09:00:00",\n    "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"\n  },\n  "endTime": {\n    "dateTime": "2019-10-30T18:00:00",\n    "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"\n  },\n  "availabilityViewInterval": 60\n}' --compressed
```

and I got this response

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.scheduleInformation)",
    "value": [
        {
            "scheduleId": "joseph.baker.doodle@outlook.com",
            "error": {
                "message": "Proxy web request failed. , inner exception: System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.\r\n   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)\r\n   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.Proxy.Service.EndGetUserAvailability(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.FreeBusyApplication.EndProxyWebRequest(ProxyWebRequest proxyWebRequest, QueryList queryList, IService service, IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.ProxyWebRequest.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.AsyncWebRequest.EndInvokeWithErrorHandling()",
                "responseCode": "ErrorProxyRequestProcessingFailed"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this a bug on Outlook side? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Where are you getting your token from in resolveAccessToken(refreshToken);? A token from another application will not work with a Graph call unless you allow it in your Azure configuration. Have you tried getting that token and making the Graph call in something like Postman?

Comment: The token is fine, the problem was in the account - it is a personal one, an it is not supported

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is not supported in Microsoft Graph API. I don't believe that calendar sharing enables access across mailboxes via the Microsoft Graph API.

Delegated access is not permitted for this API with a consumer account ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-1.0)). You are using /me which means you are trying to use delegated access.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But I also tried                                                                      ```POST /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/calendar/getSchedule```, and it doesn't work for personal accounts which is stated in the documentation. Unfortunately, in my case scenario, personal accounts can appear as well, so this endpoint won't do the trick for me.

Comment: @MagdalinaČivović please search for and support an existing feature request or open a feature request on this. https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests